# Android scaling animation to fit bounds

Tags: android, animation, textview

I have a regular textview that has "fill_parent" for width. Now, in my game that TV will perform a scale animation at some point of time - text should get bigger.
Currently, my scale initialization looks like this:

```
new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.4f, 1.0f, 1.4f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
```

which will make my textview 1.4 bigger. That's fine if i have a short text in there, but if textview to be scaled contains some longer text, parts on the text will go off the screen.

Tell me, how to dynamically define "scale factor" so it's not always 1.4, but to depend on some sort of ration between activity width and text-to-be-scaled length?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is you can read the screen size of a device and choose an appropriate scale factor according to that. To read the screen sizes of device from code, you can refer my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18299265/1952459).