# Resizing image in Android

Tags: android

I use the following method to resize images on Android.

```
public Bitmap resize(Bitmap img, int Width, int Height) {

    int width = img.getWidth();     
    int height = img.getHeight();
    int newWidth = (int) Width;
    int newHeight = (int) Height;

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // createa matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // rotate the Bitmap
    //matrix.postRotate(45);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

It works fine on most Android devices. But on some devices the resized image is not displaying. How might I resolve this?

Comment: are you calling this for static images or server images??

Comment: Sounds like you've made a good start! Could you be more precise about how the bitmap is/isn't showing: examples: is it being passed into an imageView, drawable, or being drawn directly onto a canvas?

Comment: what do you mean the image is not displaying? also, is the density of both bitmaps set to be the same?

Comment: The problem occurs for Sprite bitmap with 10 frames. The width and height of each frame is 30 percentage of screenWidth and screenHeight. i use the below code to paint the bitmap,                                                   Rect destRect = new Rect(x, y, x + spriteWidth, y + spriteHeight);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, sourceRect, destRect, paint);

Answer (score 1):

You may create a scaled bitmap with

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, true);
```

Here, width and height you can provide according to the device's screen size for different devices, by reading screen sizes programmatically. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18299265) is how you can read the screen size of a device programmatically.

Comment: I have no problem in getting the screenSize of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, on "some devices" and depending on the requested width and height, there's not enough memory to create the resized bitmap. Check (in debugger) if the `resizedBitmap` is `null` when the image "is not displaying".

Comment: image is not null after resize